# Estrutura de repetição não está verificando elementos nulos?

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho duas estruturas de repetições que percorre meu elemento e verifica se o atributo "idatributo" está nulo.

Se meu objeto tiver dois elementos, apenas o primeiro idatributo está sendo printado. O segundo é nulo, fiz uma validação pra zerar o objeto se o id for nulo.

Tentei algo como:

```
  for(let i=0;i<this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes.length;i++){
    for(let j=0;j<this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes[i].atributo.length;j++){
      console.log("idatributo:  "+this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes[i].atributo[j].idatributo)
      if(this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes[i].atributo[j].idatributo == null){
        console.log('entrou na condicao');
      }
    }
  }
```

Não está entrando na condição do if.

Meu objeto:

```
variacoes: (2) […]
​​
0: {…}
​​​
atributo: (1) […]
​​​​
0: {…}
​​​​​
idatributo: 5

1: {…}
​​​
atributo: {…}
​​​​
idatributo: null
```

Resumindo, tenho duas variacoes, dentro das variacoes tenho um atributo, em um desses atributos possui idatributo nulo, gostaria de que meu objeto (atributo) fosse reinicializado nessa condição.

Se eu trocar o id do segundo atributo ele prnita normalmente, o problema é que a condição não está sendo feita

Answer (score 0):

this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes[i].atributo[j].idatributo == 'null'